# fullfillment dialogflow code cannot connect with realtime database

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have this fullfillment dialogflow code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

...............
app.intent('Control_Devices',(conv, { devices, status }) => {
return admin.database().ref(`/ESP8266/${devices}/value`).set(status)
.then(snapshot => {
conv.ask(`OK, ${devices} ${status}. Do you want more?`);
conv.ask(new Suggestions(intentSuggestions));
});
});
```

and have an error with return admin.database().ref().set() .then(snapshot =>{});
It cannot connect with my realtime database. Can anyone help me fix this !!!!

Comment: Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Initializing firebase-admin may fail ------- This is message in firebase logs

Answer (score 0):

```
   {
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

This is my package.json
I edit to this but it isnt work

```
    {
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```